# How to update token name and decimal on solana network?

Tags: solana

I did submit PR to solana-token git repository for my token.
But I want to update my token name and decimals.
How can I do that?
I did resubmit but getting error.
[image: This is my PR request failed screenshot.]

Answer (score 0):

You've done the right thing, it will just take the developers some time to review your pull request.  The automatic checks ensure that someone isn't changing someone else's entry, and in your case, you're changing an existing entry.  They will need to double check that you put in the first request before merging this in.

Comment: So, my token name will be updated in the future?

Comment: Yes, if the pull request is approved and merged